# How to retrieve multiple author name parts separately in a latex template

Tags: yaml, latex, r-markdown, quarto

I try to write a report in quarto with _quarto.yml:

```
project:
  type: book

book:
  title: 'More of the same'
  author:
  - given-names: Ben
    surname: Fretwurst
  - given-names: Dirk 
    surname: Ursen

  chapters:
    - index.qmd

format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreport
    template: files/Template.tex
```

In the footnote of the LaTeX-template, I try to get only the surnames:

```
 {$for(by-author)$ {$by-author.surname.literal$} $sep$/ $endfor$}
```

And on the Titlepage the full names:

```
$for(by-author)$ $by-author.given-names.literal$ $by-author.surname.literal$ $sep$ and $endfor$
```

With that code, it only shows the separators in the pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "by-author" was to much and ".literal" is not needed too.

So the correct syntax is in the template:

{$for(author)$ {$author.surname$} $sep$/$endfor$}

And it gets even better: You can use given-names or affiliation after "author." Or you invent your own identifiers, like author.title or (if its relevant for you) the zodiac-sign. So you can write in the yaml:

```
book:
  title: 'More of the Same'
  author:
  - given-names: Ben
    surname: Fretwurst
    title: Dr.
    zodiac-sign: Leo
  - given-names: Ursina 
    surname: Ursen
    zodiac-sign: Twins
```

and in your LaTeX-Template for the footnote:

```
$for(author)$ {$author.surname$} $sep$/ $endfor$
```

becomes in the footnote:
[image: only surnames of the authors]

and for the titlepage:

```
$for(author)$ $if(author.title)$$author.title$$endif$ $author.given-names$ $author.surname$ $if(author.zodiac-sign)$($author.zodiac-sign$)$endif$ $sep$ and $endfor$
```

[image: title given-name and surname of the authors]